# Running google analytics script on Remix.run

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have built a web app with remix run and I want to add the Google analytics. How can I add the pure JS to head and body section without making the typescript angry?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This repository helped me out a lot: https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/google-analytics

The one thing that tripped my up for a while was that I was developing on **Brave browser** which blocks analytics.

Switching to Chrome, Firefox, Safari should do the trick.

Comment: This helped me too

Comment: The example repo was moved here: https://github.com/remix-run/examples/blob/main/google-analytics

Comment: I am also following the same repo. It has been 48 hours but still Google Analytics says `No data received in past 48 hours`. I have obtained the tracking ID (G-XXXXXXXX) and updated my `process.env` file, rest of the code is the same as the example repo. I want to track the site running on my `localhost`, so while setting up the data stream, I simply put `www.example.com` as the URL. Is that the reason of not getting any data? I get `window.gtag is not defined. This could mean your google analytics script has not loaded on the page yet.` warning on browser (Firefox).

Answer (score 11):

> On any page, at anytime, you can flip between plain HTML and full
> client-side transitions.
>
> If you need one tiny bit of interactivity, use a

```
<script
 dangerouslySetInnerHTML>.
```

Example, taken from https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/disabling-javascript

```
return (
  <>
    <select id="qty">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option value="contact">
        Contact Sales for more
      </option>
    </select>

    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            document.getElementById('qty').onchange = (event) => {
              if (event.target.value === "contact") {
                window.location.assign("/contact")
              }
            }
          });
        `
      }}
    />
  </>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remix is after all a React framework you have to make use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to add the content of your setup script to your `root.txt` file.

I made this short "how to ? " page that you can follow https://tipminers.com/tips/50/How-to-add-google-analytics-to-a-Remix-Run-Web-App

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.